# Different fonts for different languages (English and Persian)

Tags: linux, arch-linux, konsole, fontconfig

I constantly use English and [Persian (Farsi)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persian_language) in my day-to-day use. And I want to set different fonts for each of them, in [arch-linux](/questions/tagged/arch-linux).

Namely, I want to use [Iosevka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iosevka) for English, and [Sahel](https://github.com/rastikerdar/sahel-font) for Persian. From what I've gathered, one of the few Terminal emulators that support bi-directionality is [Konsole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konsole). So I'm using that, and it does show Persian letters properly.

From [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Font_configuration), it's suggested to use [Fontconfig](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/fontconfig/). So I created this config file, in `~/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
<match target="font">
        <test name="lang" compare="contains">
                <string>ar</string>
        </test>
        <alias>
                <family>sans-serif</family>
                <prefer>
                        <family>Sahel</family>
                </prefer>
        </alias>
</match>
</fontconfig>
```

And I've made sure that the font is installed:

```
❯ fc-list | grep "Sahel.ttf"
/home/amir/.fonts/sahel-font/dist/Sahel.ttf: Sahel:style=Regular
```

But it doesn't work:

[image]

It should look like this:

[image]

But this way, it also sets the Sahel font for English text, which is not pretty.

I've also made sure to log out of X session when making changes to `fonts.conf`. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for being too late to answer your problem but I have a solution for that.
the problem with your font is that it is considered "arabic" and not persian. to fix that problem just add this small line of code to your fonts.conf:

```
      <match>
      <test name="lang" compare="contains"><string>fa</string></test>
      <edit name="lang" mode="assign" binding="same"><string>ar</string></edit>
      </match>
```

I hope you see this (even though I'm 3 years late :D)